# New Caller Insert to Database with Codeigniter using the Twilio API

Tags: codeigniter, twilio

Below is the function to receive all incoming calls in my Controller

```
public function call_incoming()
{
    $blocklist = $this->call_log_model->get_blocklist($_REQUEST['From']);
    $tenantNum = $this->call_log_model->get_called_tenant($_REQUEST['From']);
    $tenantInfoByNumber = $this->account_model->getTenantInfoByNumber($tenantNum->to_tenant);
    $officeStatus = $this->check_office_hours($tenantInfoByNumber->start_office_hours, $tenantInfoByNumber->end_office_hours);
    $calldisposition = $this->calldisp_model->get_call_disposition($tenantInfoByNumber->user_id);

    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;

    if($blocklist == 0)
    {
        if($officeStatus == "open")
        {
            if($_POST['Called'] != AGENTPOOL_NUM)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'caller'=>$_REQUEST['From'],
                    'to_tenant'=>$_POST['Called'],
                    'date_created'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
                $this->call_log_model->insert_caller_to_tenant($data);

                $dial = $response->dial(NULL, array('callerId' => $_REQUEST['From']));
                $dial->number(AGENTPOOL_NUM);
                print $response;
            }
            else
            {
                $gather = $response->gather(array('numDigits' => 1, 'action'=>HTTP_BASE_URL.'agent/call_controls/call_incoming_pressed', 'timeout'=>'5' , 'method'=>'POST'));
                $ctr = 1;
                foreach($calldisposition as $val )
                {
                    $gather->say('To go to '.$val->disposition_name.', press '.$ctr, array('voice' => 'alice'));
                    $gather->pause("");
                    $ctr++;
                }
                print $response;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response->say('Thank you for calling. Please be advise that our office hours is from '.$tenantInfoByNumber->start_office_hours.' to '.$tenantInfoByNumber->end_office_hours);
            $response->hangup();
            print $response;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $response->say('This number is blocked. Goodbye!');
        $response->hangup();
        print $response;
    }
}
```

Please advise if I need to post the model...

Here is whats happening everytime an unknown number calls in, the caller will hear an application error has occurred error message and when checking the Twilio console the error it is giving me is

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> > Severity: Notice 
> >        Message:  Trying to get property of non-object 
> >        Filename: agent/Call_controls.php 
> >        Line Number: 357

Please be advised that this error only occurs when the caller is a number not in our database yet. When the call comes from a number already saved in our databse, this codes works...

Thank you for the help...

Comment: Can you inform us as to what line 357 is?

Comment: it is `$tenantInfoByNumber = $this->account_model->getTenantInfoByNumber($tenantNum->to_tenant);`

Comment: `if($tenantNum) { 
    $tenantInfoByNumber = $this->account_model->getTenantInfoByNumber($tenantNum->to_tenant);
 } else { 
    $tenantInfoByNumber = ""; // fill this in with relevant fill data
}`

Comment: will try this i will give a feed back in a few minutes

Comment: please post an answer it solved my problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($tenantNum) { 
  $tenantInfoByNumber = $this->account_model->getTenantInfoByNumber($tenantNum->to_t‌​enant); 
} else { 
  $tenantInfoByNumber = ""; // fill this in with relevant fill data 
}
```

This should fix your issue, as there is no TenantNum returned, there is no data, so [make it yourself for unknown numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call).